# How to set custom start position in GNU Chess?

Tags: engines

I could not find this in the GNU Chess manual by searching, although I might be overlooking it, under a different name.

What I am seeking to do with GNU Chess is quite simple: Specifying the position of every single piece on the board, for both players, and deciding who starts after that. I'm currently reading a beginner's book on Chess, as I know nearly nothing about it, and would like to follow the tutorials, which suggest to start with particular positions with a chess computer or advanced player, and figure out how to survive.

The optimal feature would be having the possibility to keep those starting positions in text files, so that I can reuse them and modify them.

Answer (score 3):

[The manual can be found on GNU Chess's website](https://www.gnu.org/software/chess/manual/). To set a custom position, use the setboard command followed by the FEN string of the game position.

Comment: The manual linked doesn't mention the setboard command. It does mention the epdload command, however. setboard is an x-board command.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Indeed `setboard` does not seem to be part of the [commands list](https://www.gnu.org/software/chess/manual/html_node/Command-list.html), although `epdload` is. Thanks for pointing this out. So, if I go something like `gnuchess epdload filename` in Bash, it just starts a game with the position specified in the extended position description file? Thanks again.